# Is the constructor of my pages in my app only called once, ever?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Im creating an app with multiple pages. OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom iscalled each time i enter and leave a page.

But when is the constructor of a page called, and does the app kill it and call the constructor again when i just navigate between my pages?

Are there any exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A page is killed only when it's not on the `BackStack` assuming there are no resource leaks on that page ofcourse. That is why MainPage's constructor is only called once because it is always in the `BackStack`.

So for example giving the following page navigation order, constructor call will be:

```
MainPage --> Page1 --> Page2 --> Go Back(Page 1) --> Go Back (MainPage) --> Page1
Ctor     --> Ctor  --> Ctor  -->                 -->                    --> Ctor
```

As you can see, going back from Page2 to Page1 won't call Page1's constructor because it is still on the `BackStack`. However, once back at MainPage then navigation to Page1 will call Page1's constructor because it was no longer in the `BackStack`.